# Format string as currency REGEX

Tags: javascript, regex, netsuite, str-replace, suitescript1.0

I'm currently trying to transform some data before displaying on NetSuite server side with suitescript 1.

Unfortunately, can't use *toLocaleString*.

| Data | Output | Expected |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1000USD | 1,000.00 USD |
| 1 | 1EUR | 1.00 EUR |
| 2000000.1 | 2000000.1GBD | 2,000,000.10 GBD |

Any idea how I can accomplish that? mostly looking to do it with a simple function like this one

```
fuction formatThis(str){
  return String(str).replace(/(.)(?=(\d{3})+$)/g, '$1,');
}
```

Comment: *"Unfortunately, can't use toLocaleString."*: eh, why not? You tagged this with `javascript`, and that method belongs to the language specification.

Comment: @trincot because I'm in NetSuite and the application doesn't work with normal, everyday Javascript. For example, we can't use "let" or "const" to declare a new variable, only "var". _toLocaleString_ is one of those things that just doesn't work ‍♂️

Comment: OK, must be an older version of NetSuite then. Version 2.1 supports most ECMA Script features. Can you tell me how it is decided which currency to display? In your table with examples, there is no currency on the input side, yet it appears magically on the output side.

Comment: @N Vargas: Does one of the answers address your needs? If so would you care to accept it? If not, add some more details to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If your version of NetSuite is 2.0, you may only have access to ECMA Script 5.1

Here is a function that would do the formatting without using ECMAScript 2015 features. It takes a second argument for the currency. I don't see that anywhere in your examples on the input side:

```js
function format(str, currency) {
    return (str + ".00")
        .replace(/(\.\d)\.00/, "$10")
        .replace(/\.+(\d{0,2}).*/, ".$1 " + currency)
        .replace(/\d(?=(\d{3})+\b)/g, "$&,");
}

// Examples:
console.log(format("1000", "USD"));
console.log(format("1", "EUR"));
console.log(format("2000000.1", "GBD"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the leading number, and format the currency using a bunch of regexes:

```js
function formatCurrency(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[0-9\.]+/, function(m) { // extract the leading number
    return parseInt(Number(m) * 100, 10)        // convert the number to cents
      .toString()                 // convert back to string
      .replace(/(..)$/, '.$1')    // add dot, e.g. restore currency from cents
      .replace(/(.)(.{12})$/, '$1,$2') // add comma to billion
      .replace(/(.)(.{9})$/, '$1,$2')  // add comma to million
      .replace(/(.)(.{6})$/, '$1,$2')  // add comma to thousand
      + ' ';
  });
}

[
  '1000USD',
  '999CHF',
  '1EUR',
  '2000000.1GBD'
].forEach(function(str) {
  console.log(str + ' => ' + formatCurrency(str));
});
```

Output:

```
1000USD => 1,000.00 USD
999CHF => 999.00 CHF
1EUR => 1.00 EUR
2000000.1GBD => 2,000,000.10 GBD
```